# External listing of dynamic marker info of current view

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to figure out how to display dynamic markers in the form of a list within a separate div using openlayers, however I'm hoping to only display those seen within the current view. This means that whenever the map is moved, the list of marker info changes. Does anyone have any suggestions for achieving this? I'm still learning openlayers, so I apologize if the answer to this question should be obvious. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you store your markers? Do you have a map server in the backend, or an xml file or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could register for the map's `moveend` event and check which features are displayed using the `onScreen()` method.

```js
var map = new Openlayer.Map( ... );
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( ... );

map.events.register('moveend', this, function() {
    var displayedFeatures = [];

    for (var i=0, len=layer.features.length; i<len; i++) {
        var feature = layer.features[i];
        if (feature.onScreen())
            displayedFeatures.push(feature);
    }

    //Do somthing with displayedFeatures

});
```